# NSLocalizedString versus switch language from app

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

I need to use Localization to switch Language when button click.

I've tried this, bug the element doesn't refresh.

-they are set like this:

```
self.lblSectionMyPictures.text=NSLocalizedString(@"lblSectionMyPictures", nil);
```

Code to switch:

```
- (void)SwitchToFrench{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fr", nil]
                                              forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
 }

- (void)SwitchToEnglish{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil]
                                              forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
 }
```

Any idea\best practice?

Answer (score 1):

Apple's solution for localization does not support switching localizations on-the-fly. The strings are loaded once and never changed then.

If you are persistent at pursuing switching languages on the fly (which is sort of unachievable ideal in my experience), I think your best bet is to create your own KVO-compliant localization strings provider and bind every GUI element (button's title, text field's value, etc) to it. With AutoLayout enabled, that might even work.